# Can I find excerpt/Wiki of a tag that is now a synonym of another tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-excerpt, tag-wiki

Can I find (the old) excerpt/Wiki of a tag that is now a synonym of another tag?

E.g. the excerpt and Wiki of the [arima](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima) tag builds on ARMA (does not discuss what ARMA is). But since [arma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma) has been made a synonym of [arima](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima), the excerpt and Wiki of [arima](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima) now would need an update to explain what ARMA is. I wanted to borrow these from the [arma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma) tag, but I do not know how to access its (old) excerpt and Wiki now that the tag no longer exists independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky but doable.

Go to http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags and type "arma". You will see the original [arma](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma) tag with its own question count and excerpt (this is because it was never *merged* into [arima](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima)). There is an "edit" link there too, leading to http://stats.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/830 -- and this gets you where you want.

Comment: How cool! Thanks!